# PCIe Error Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, nvidia, 18.04, pcie, dual-graphics

I am encountering the often-seen PCIe error on a relatively new build PC after installing Ubuntu server 18.04.  It occurs immediately after installing the nVidia 410 driver set.  The error rolls across the screen constantly and prevents proper booting.  It will go on forever as far as I can tell, I let it go for 30 minutes on one boot attempt.  The only thing that will stop it is flipping the switch on the power supply.  I can then reboot into recovery mode and try some of the so-called fixes for this problem.  I’ve tried 4 or 5 fixes so far (turning off secure boot, editing the GRUB file with nomsi and noaer, etc), none of them work.  I would appreciate any assistance the community can offer, thanks in advance.  All the hardware details are below, should you be interesting in assisting me with this confounding problem.

Motherboard:  ASUS Prime Z270-P, which has onboard Intel video, network, sound
Processor: Intel Celeron G3900 2.8GHz 2 MB Cache LGA1151
Memory:  Kingston 8GB ValueRam, 2x4GB
Power Supply:  EVGA 1000 GQ
Video Cards: Two Gigabyte Geforce GTX 1070 Windforce OC 8GB GDDRS

As you can see, nothing crazy about this hardware, although I do want to run 2 video cards. This system was running fine on Windows 10 Pro, except for the usual persistent issues with Windows – bugs, constant updates, privacy issues, etc - so I decided to try Ubuntu server instead.

The PC will boot using either onboard video or 1 of the nVidia cards.  If I plug in both nVidia cards, it will not boot at all.  With some combinations I will get the “blind boot” message, which as far as I can tell does not result in a boot at all; I can’t ssh into the machine after one of these instances and the local screen remains blank.  Guess that’s why they call it “blind”.  :)

When I encounter the PCIe error after installing the nVidia drivers, I shut down at the power supply.  Then I would reboot into recovery and try one of the fixes, they never worked, then I would just re-install Ubuntu server from the USB stick.  I’m getting pretty fast at it after about 5 installs.

Since nothing has worked so far, I’m requesting assistance before proceeding further.  Again, thanks should you decide to help.  I have noticed that many of these PCIe error request questions go unanswered, but I’m hopeful.   If I can’t get past this, guess it’s back to Windows 10 Pro (yuck).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu forums......help those that help themselves.  Or so it seems.

I searched and tried over half a dozen solutions to this problem on this forum.  Nothing worked - all of them ran into issues at one point or another.

But I was successful in finding an answer.  I would suggest others having this same issue read the article at the website below.  It worked for me.

[The Best Way To Install Ubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia Drivers](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/The-Best-Way-To-Install-Ubuntu-18-04-with-NVIDIA-Drivers-and-any-Desktop-Flavor-1178/)